# How to access elements of other component in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two components `Playlist` and `Vol-Slider`,I want to access `vol-Slider` component inside `Playlist` component the thing I wanna do is whenever someone clicks on icons a class should be added to the `vol-slider` component as well.

Playlist Component

```
export default function Playlist() {
  function toggleClass(e) {
    e.currentTarget.classList.toggle("active");
  }

  return (
    <div id="playlist-container">
      <div id="playlist">
        <div className="icons" onClick={toggleClass}>
          <BsCloudRain />
          <VolSlider />
        </div>
        <div className="icons" onClick={toggleClass}>
          <GiForest />
          <VolSlider />
        </div>
        <div className="icons" onClick={toggleClass}>
          <MdOutlineWaterDrop />
          <VolSlider />
        </div>
        <div className="icons" onClick={toggleClass}>
          <BiWind />
          <VolSlider />
        </div>
        <div className="icons" onClick={toggleClass}>
          <GiCampfire />
          <VolSlider />
        </div>
        <div className="icons" onClick={toggleClass}>
          <GiThreeLeaves />
          <VolSlider />
        </div>
        <div className="icons" onClick={toggleClass}>
          <BsMoonStars />
          <VolSlider />
        </div>
        <div className="icons" onClick={toggleClass}>
          <BiWater />
          <VolSlider />
        </div>
        <div className="icons" onClick={toggleClass}>
          <BiTrain />
          <VolSlider />
        </div>
        <div className="icons" onClick={toggleClass}>
          <BiCoffeeTogo />
          <VolSlider />
        </div>
        <div className="icons" onClick={toggleClass}>
          <FaFan />
          <VolSlider />
        </div>
        <div className="icons" onClick={toggleClass}>
          <DiDigitalOcean />
          <VolSlider />
        </div>
        <div className="icons" onClick={toggleClass}>
          <GiWaterfall />
          <VolSlider />
        </div>
        <div className="icons" onClick={toggleClass}>
          <FaPlane />
          <VolSlider />
        </div>
        <div className="icons" onClick={toggleClass}>
          <IoIosPlanet />
          <VolSlider />
        </div>
        <div className="icons" onClick={toggleClass}>
          <GiOctopus />
          <VolSlider />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Volume Slider Component

```
export default function volSlider() {
  return (
    <div id="vol-slider-div">
      <input className="vol-slider" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React, instead of using `toggle`, you can use states to handle UI updates. With this approach, you can pass states to any components for conditional renderings.

**Playlist**

```
//reduce your code duplication, and re-use `isActive` state for each icon
function PlaylistItem({ children }) {
   const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false)

   function toggleClass() {
      setIsActive(!isActive) //toggle active value
   }

   return (<div className={`icons ${isActive && "active"}`} onClick={toggleClass}>
          {children}
          <VolSlider isActive={isActive}/>
   </div>)
}

export default function Playlist() {

  return (
    <div id="playlist-container">
      <div id="playlist">
        <PlaylistItem>
          <BsCloudRain />
        </PlaylistItem>
        <PlaylistItem>
          <GiForest />
        </PlaylistItem>
        <PlaylistItem>
          <VolSlider />
        </PlaylistItem>
        <PlaylistItem>
          <BiWind />
        </PlaylistItem>
        <PlaylistItem>
          <GiCampfire />
        </PlaylistItem>
        <PlaylistItem>
          <GiThreeLeaves />
        </PlaylistItem>
        <PlaylistItem>
          <BsMoonStars />
        </PlaylistItem>
        <PlaylistItem>
          <BiWater />
        </PlaylistItem>
        <PlaylistItem>
          <BiTrain />
        </PlaylistItem>
        <PlaylistItem>
          <BiCoffeeTogo />
        </PlaylistItem>
        <PlaylistItem>
          <FaFan />
        </PlaylistItem>
        <PlaylistItem>
          <DiDigitalOcean />
        </PlaylistItem>
        <PlaylistItem>
          <GiWaterfall />
        </PlaylistItem>
        <PlaylistItem>
          <FaPlane />
        </PlaylistItem>
        <PlaylistItem>
          <IoIosPlanet />
        </PlaylistItem>
        <PlaylistItem>
          <GiOctopus />
        </PlaylistItem>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**VolSlider**

```
//pass props `isActive` for class update according to state changes from `PlaylistItem`
export default function volSlider({ isActive }) {
  return (
    <div id="vol-slider-div" onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}>
      <input className={`vol-slider ${isActive && "active"}`} type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: bro what does this part do `className={`icons ${isActive && "active"}`}`, I know about and operator(&&). 

ps - your code is working for me but actually I mistakenly created `vol-slider` div inside the icons div so whenever I am clicking the slider the whole div get closed I don't want that.

you can see the result here -> [Click me to see the result](https://wfinqg.csb.app/)

Comment: you can set `onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}` on `vol-slider-div`. Here is [the document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) for it. By the way, I updated my answer for it. Besides that, className is actually a prop, so you can pass [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to handle conditional class names @KaranRajput

Comment: That solves my problem, but sorry I still  didn't get the `{`vol-slider ${isActive && "active"}`}` part, is it saying that if `isActive` is true then use `"active"` if it is false then don't ? 
ps - I know about template literals, but haven't used like this.

Comment: Basically, the conditions are checked from left to right, if `isActive` is true, it will check the next condition (all other languages also have this), but in this case, the next one is not a boolean, so Javascript will use it as a new value. This behavior is only in Javascript. @KaranRajput

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend storing a state of whether the class is toggled on or off in your playlist component. You can do this like so:

```
const [isClassToggled, setIsClassToggled] = useState(false);
```

Then, I would suggest passing this state as a prop into your VolSlider component. You can do this like so:

```
<VolSlider classToggled={isClassToggled} />
```

Then in your VolSlider component, you would apply a class if this prop is true. This can be done like so:

```js
export default function volSlider() {
  return (
    <div id="vol-slider-div">
      <input className={`vol-slider ${props.classToggled ? "classToShowWhenToggled" : "ClassToShowWhenNotToggled" }`} type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

This makes use of an experession to test the value of a variable and display a different value based on true or false using ? and : .
The same logic can be replicated to apply classes in the Playlist component but you would do `isClassToggled` rather than `props.classToggled`.